# How to detect and manage disk/registry/network activity performed by a loaded DLL?

Tags: c#, security, networking, io, registry

Assuming my application implements a plugin/extension system which allows the user to dynamically load and execute code from external DLL files, how would I go about managing security in terms of **disk**, **registry** and **network** access (read/write/delete)?

To be more specific, I would like to be able to know when a plugin/extension is about to perform a disk/registry/network operation, intercept that action and allow or deny it based on a set of predefined rules or simply by asking the user if they allow a certain type of access to that particular plugin.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a sanity check or a security boundary?  For the latter, your only options are (1) a separate process running as a different user or (2) an interpreted (or JIT compiled by a compiler you control) scripting language that simply has no way to address the system calls directly.  There's simply no way to prevent in-process binary code from doing whatever it wants (up to the limit of what you can do).

Comment: Notably, user-mode code can always escape attempts by other user-mode code to intercept it.  Just a few ways: (a) Pass legal arguments to the approved interface, but from another thread overwrite the file name just before it is passed to the OS.  (b) Bypass the approved interface and dynamically link to OS functions directly.  (c) Do it without calling any library API function at all, instead load the parameters and make a system call.

Comment: @BenVoigt roughly, the way my plugin/extensions implementation works is that it loads the entry point from valid extension DLLs, and these extension DLLs can then do whatever through the host application.
I'm looking to implement a monitoring system that is capable of detecting disk/registry/network operations and to block or allow such operations based on a set of rules or user input (similarly to how anti-virus software works).

Comment: @BenVoigt Having a second process monitor the process that loads the extensions sounds like a good idea and I would go with it, and in this regard, I would prefer c# code samples which demonstrate how one process can detect the disk/registry/network activity of another and suspend it until the user allows or denies that operation (which I am guessing is how AVs work). So yeah, I would go this route.

Comment: No, I didn't mean you monitor your main process from outside, I meant the plugins are sandboxed in a separate process running as an unprivileged user.  That way they cannot ask the OS to do anything directly (well, they can ask, but the kernel will deny all attempts due to process running as a locked-down user).  In this model, plugins can only make requests to the main application, allowing the main app to apply the rules before performing the action.  Anti-virus software uses kernel code to get its job done.

Comment: If you're using .NET and allows only .NET plugins, you can use sandboxing (AppDomains) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox

Comment: @BenVoigt using separate processes or appdomains to hoset the extensions is not an option for my implementation; I want to find a way to detect system operations (internally or by using a satellite process) that are executed by routines that are part of a loaded DLL.

Comment: @IneedHelp: You will need kernel-mode code to do that.  Your problem is that you are trying to patch access control on after choosing your implementation, when it really needs to be designed in before a single line of code is written.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was thinking more about something in line with Sysinternals' Procmon and Tcpview which show detailed aspects about what an application is doing on disk/registry/network, but I do realize that these actions are detected after an action occurred and it can't be prevented in time or suspended until a decision is made.

Comment: @IneedHelp: [Some of those tools actually install a kernel driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon), the other ones miss stuff.  Only the kernel can reliably intercept syscalls (handling syscalls is the entire thing that makes a kernel work, btw), user-mode can only hook into convenience functions, and those convenience functions are optional.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think I am starting to better understand what you're saying; so I guess what I am looking for is a lightweight version of an application that acts like an anti-virus with HIPS + firewall and polices itself or most likely a targeted process and oversees what the target process is doing in regard to system operations; can this be achieved with C# and the use of system libraries?

Comment: No, but you can probably find a kernel driver that does the interception, and then sends the details to a user-mode program to make the decision on whether to approve or deny the request.  That user-mode program could be written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

For the absolute solution you will have to use a kernel driver to intercept requests. but if you don't need 100%, you can develop a tool similar to [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).

The tool hook API functions, (there are few such libraries, MSDetour, Mhook, etc) and can record the call or break on call. knowing which module called the API is possible too, by examining the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Some control can be achieved using AppDomains and Code Access Security. You can create sandboxed AppDomain and grant it permissions to directories you want your plugin to access. If plugin attempts to acess file outside of them, you get SecurityException.

For example, if we have following ClassLib.dll plugin:

```
namespace ClassLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string DoWork(string path)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
    }
}
```

We can invoke it with restricted permissions like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        //Path to plugin library
        public static string libname = @"C:\PROJECTS\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ClassLib.dll";

        //Invokes plugin library in restricted AppDomain
        //Grants access to the directory specified by allowedPath parameter
        static void InvokeLibrary(string allowedPath="")
        {
            var path = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;

            //create restricted permission set
            Evidence evidence = new Evidence();
            evidence.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Internet));
            PermissionSet permissionSet = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(evidence);

            //grant read access to plugin library file, so it can at least load successfully
            permissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, libname));
            permissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, libname));

            //grant read access to
            if (allowedPath != "")
            {
                permissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, allowedPath));
            }            

            AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
            appDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            //create AppDomain with specified permissions
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
                "MyDomain",
                evidence,
                appDomainSetup,
                permissionSet
                );

            //create remoting wrapper
            Type type = typeof(Wrapper);
            Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                type.Assembly.FullName,
                type.FullName);

            //invoke method          
            InvokeResult res = wrapper.Invoke(libname,"c:\\dir\\file.txt");

            if (res.Success) Console.WriteLine("Invoke result: " + res.Result);
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoke error: " + res.Error.GetType().ToString());
                if (res.Error is SecurityException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Demanded permissions:\n" + (res.Error as SecurityException).Demanded);
                }
            }                    

            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //invoke plugin without explicit permissions
            Console.WriteLine("First attempt...");
            InvokeLibrary();

            //invoke plugin with specified directory access
            Console.WriteLine("Second attempt...");
            InvokeLibrary("c:\\dir\\");   

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    //Object to pass between app domains
    public class InvokeResult : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public bool Success = false;
        public string Result="";
        public Exception Error =null;
    }

    //Wrapper for remoting
    public class Wrapper : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Exception lasterror;

        public InvokeResult Invoke(string lib, string arg)
        {
            InvokeResult res = new InvokeResult();

            try
            {
                //load plugin                
                Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(lib);
                Type t = ass.GetType("ClassLib.Class1");
                MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("DoWork", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                //invoke plugin method
                res.Result = (string)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { arg });
                res.Success = true;

            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                res.Success = false;
                if (ex.InnerException != null) res.Error = ex.InnerException;
                else res.Error = ex;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}

/* Output:

First attempt...
Invoke error: System.Security.SecurityException
Demanded permissions:
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Read="c:\dir\file.txt"/>

Second attempt...
Invoke result: The content of file.txt 
*/
```